# Laravel and AJAX doesn't return anything

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to return data from my database with `.ajax()` but it throws out an error with the entire HTML of a page. Why is it doing that?

My `.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        group_id : $('#group').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

route

```
Route::get('reports/groupsUsersGet',
    array(
        'as' =>'groupsUsersGet',
        'uses' => 'ReportsController@groupsUsersGet'
    )
);
```

view(form)

```
{{ Form::select('grup',$group,null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'group']) }}
```

controller

```
$term = Input::get('group_id');
$results = array();
DB::table('users')->where('group', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $results[] = [
        'id' => $query->id,
        'value' => $query->nick
    ];
}

return Response::json($results);
```

Comment: What is the error? What does you expect?

Comment: From where does the `$query` comes from? Can you please specify it.

Comment: Use try and catch and tell the exact error u are getting

Comment: error returns 200 and status ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also send the `csrf_token()` as data.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
         _token: <?php echo csrf_token();?>,
          group_id : $('#group').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: groupsUsersGet:1061 Uncaught ReferenceError: XREXnSgsYpN3kJwjXGPguiJYZf6XIYxQa7YsYgDz is not defined(…) when I throw token part without it ajax error gives state: 200 and status ok(which mean it passed).

Comment: ya XREXnSgsYpN3kJwjXGPguiJYZf6XIYxQa7YsYgDz this the value of token that send.Just take the value of group id.

Comment: For more see here http://dev.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm

Comment: `Route` must be post.

Comment: You don't need a token in GET request. And routes can be different for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you aren't sending CSRF token in the request, as @HikmatSijapati specified. In ajax request you can pass csrf token like this:

You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your controller you can't define `$queries` variable inside your method.

> ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",        
    data: {
        group_id : $('#group').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

> controller

```
$term = Input::get('group_id');
$results = array();
$queries = DB::table('users')->where('group', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $results[] = [
        'id' => $query->id,
        'value' => $query->nick
    ];
}

return Response::json(['results' => $results], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help but the error was in my not including use Response at the top of controller. When I did that it worked.